# showing memory addresses with Console.Writeline

Tags: c#, reference, console.writeline

I have this code in a c# console application:

```
int x = 10;
int* ptr1 = &x;
Console.WriteLine((int)ptr1);
Console.WriteLine((long)ptr1);
Console.WriteLine((ulong)ptr1);
```

Why do I get a diferente value for the int datatype? Is it because of the 2,147,483,647 limit for `int`?

```
-1529354580
453737178796
453737178796
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you build for x64 architecture .
The size of addresses in x64 is 64 bits (8 bytes).
A pointer contains an address, in your case of the data of type `int`.
This address cannot be fit into an `int` because its size is only 32 bits (4 bytes).

The value is truncated, and this is what you see when you use:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)ptr1);
```

By truncated I mean that the compiler will take 4 bytes of the address, and store them in a 32bit storage (int). You'll loose 4 bytes, and if the value exceeds the maximum for int, the result will be quite meaningless.

The other 2 print lines:

```
Console.WriteLine((long)ptr1);
Console.WriteLine((ulong)ptr1);
```

cast the pointer into a 64bit type (`long` or `ulong`) and therefore you get the whole address.

In principle you can also have different outputs for `long` and `ulong`. But since addresses are always positive and usually within the valid range for `long` you didn't encounter this issue.

BTW - If you'll build for x86 (32bit architecture), pointers will have the size of 4 bytes and therefore all your print lines will print the same value.

Comment: I suspected but was more interested in understanding the "The value is truncated" part! Showld´t i get an error instead of that?

Comment: No, because using the cast to `(int)` you actually tell the compiler you are aware of the issue.

Comment: Added more about truncation in the answer body above.